# SQL Server query SUM from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I came across an issue I cannot figure out unfortunately...

I have 2 tables: Purchase Orders Lines AND Sales Orders Lines.
Now I need to pull info from a single PO AND also SUM of cases of a particular item (listed on that PO) FROM both Sales orders lines AND Purchase Orders lines. Like I am ordering 10 tables and I want to know that I already ordered 20 tables and I have sales orders for 25 tables. Below is my query.

```sql
SELECT s.POLID, s.ItemID, s.CSordered,
SUM(sl.CSopen) AS CSopenSO, SUM(pl.CSopen) AS CSopenPO
FROM PurchaseOrdersLines s

LEFT JOIN SalesOrdersLines sl ON s.ItemID = sl.ItemID
LEFT JOIN PurchaseOrdersLines pl ON s.ItemID = pl.ItemID

WHERE s.POID = '" . $row['POID'] . "'
GROUP BY s.POLID, s.ItemID, s.CSordered
```

I am getting SUM of CSopenSO correct but not SUM CSopenPO (it is 50 times higher than it should be). If I switch LEFT JOIN bringing Purchase Orders (pl) first then Sales Orders (sl) - then I get correct SUM of CSopenPO but not SUM of CSopenSO. I do not understand how the order of LEFT JOIN affects the sums and how to avoid it.

Thank you for your help in advance!!!
Hope if it was clear..

*** Suggested by Jarlh

```sql
SELECT s.POLID, s.ItemID, s.CSordered, (
SELECT SUM(CSopen) FROM SalesOrdersLines sl WHERE sl.ItemID = s.ItemID
) AS CSopenSO, SUM(pl.CSopen) AS CSopenPO 
FROM PurchaseOrdersLines s
LEFT JOIN PurchaseOrdersLines pl ON s.ItemID = pl.ItemID
WHERE s.POID = '" . $row['POID'] . "'
GROUP BY s.POLID, s.ItemID, s.CSordered
```

However I still want to understand why my original query above is not working the way I want it to work. I would like to know what the error is.

Comment: JOIN's and GROUP BY combined require some extra care. Try to GROUP BY in subqueries before JOIN-ing. (Or, if you're lazy, skip the joins and the group by, instead put correlated subqueries in the select list.)

Comment: Thank you Jarlh for a suggestion, I moved one of the JOINs to a subquery in select, it worked. However I still want to understand why my original query is not working the way I want it to work. I would like to know what the error is.

Comment: The error is in your join logic. remove the summing and add the pk and fk columns of the various tables and then perhaps limit the resultset to a single item to see how your join actually works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often, correlated subqueries are the most efficient method:

```
SELECT s.POLID, s.ItemID, s.CSordered,
       (SELECT SUM(sl.CSopen)
        FROM SalesOrdersLines sl 
        WHERE s.ItemID = sl.ItemID
       )  AS CSopenSO,
       (SELECT SUM(pl.CSopen)
        FROM PurchaseOrdersLines pl 
        WHERE s.ItemID = pl.ItemID
       ) AS CSopenPO 
FROM PurchaseOrdersLines s
WHERE s.POID = '" . $row['POID'] . "';
```

This assumes that the rows in `s` are not being combined.

Comment: Thank you, Gordon, However.. is there way to do that without subqueries?

Comment: @MaxCB . . . You could pre-aggregate using CTEs.  But no, there is not really a way to do this without subqueries of some sort.